# What is causing random misses when pasting Excel cells to Power Point table cells?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Every month, I run a VBA program to update the previous month's data table (on a Power Point slide) with new data (which I take from an Excel file).  I use the following VBA function to paste the data.

```
Function PastePcts(ByVal tbl As PowerPoint.Table,
    ByVal oldRow As Long, ByVal oldCol As Long,
    ByVal newRow As Integer, ByVal newCol As Integer)
'
' This function basically pastes data from Cell (oldRow, oldCol) of the current Excel
' spreadsheet to Cell (newRow, newCol) of the input PowerPoint table
'
    Cells(oldRow, oldCol).Copy
    With tbl.Cell(newRow, newCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Paste 'Pastes new percent
        Call .Replace("%","") 'Removes % sign
        .Font.Bold = True 'Restores boldface
    End With
End Function
```

Most cells on the PowerPoint table change as expected, but a few of them at random keep their value from the previous month like this function was never called on them.  If I run the program again, I am likely to get the same problems, but the set of table cells that keep their old value will be different.

On my last run, the table had 88 cells whose value changed from last month, 78 of which changed successfully.  How can I modify the code to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just setting the value of the powerpoint cell rather than copying the whole Excel cell. Using the clipboard is usually slower and not as reliable as handling strings/numerical values. Especially between different applications (Office can't use its own clipboard between instances even of the same application.)

```
With tbl.Cell(newRow, newCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = Cells(oldRow, oldCol).Value
    Call .Replace("%","") 'Removes % sign
    .Font.Bold = True 'probably not necessary any more
End With
```

Depending on the excel cell's formatting you might have to do some tweaking

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tried your suggestion and everything copied perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a timing issue to me. Can you confirm by setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code for all 88 cells to check if all are populated? I've experienced similar issue with Copy/Paste loops of large quantities in PowerPoint and never found a solution even though I've tried the following:

1. Adding **DoEvents** after the **.Copy** method to try tho give the OS time for the clipboard to be populated.
2. Putting the **.Paste** method in a **Do...While** loop and checking for **Err=0** before continuing.
3. Slowing things down with a simple WinAPI **Sleep** call.
4. Interrogating the clipboard data type (more complex WinAPI calls) before executing the **.Paste** method to check for valid content.

Maybe one of the above methods will work in your case though. However, when it randomly fails in my code, I get an error along the lines of "data cannot be pasted here" so unless you've removed error handling from your posted code maybe the cause is something entirely different.

I think there is something fundamentally wrong with the interaction between VBA and the underlying OS regarding this random behaviour...